# FAQ has wrong value for reopen

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) has conflicting values for being able to vote to close/reopen. It lists both 250 and 3000. There might be other parts that need to be updated too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

250  Vote to close, reopen, or migrate **your** questions

3000     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate **any** questions

They're different things.

Comment: Doh, thanks... I didn't see it. Still getting over not having the close/reopen privilege yet. This site is closing way too many good questions ever since getting out of beta.